# Need AeroLite dll for .net framework 4.0

Tags: .net, dll, .net-4.0, frameworks

hello can anyone help me to get PresentationFramework.Aerolite.dll. I am not ablke to find it on internet.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This DLL is not part of .NET 4.0.

It was introduced in .NET 4.5. You will need to [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)  and install that version of the framework in order to gain access to this assembly.

You cannot, of course, just download random DLL files online and expect them to work with older software that does not support them.